# Java Multi-threaded Client Server application using MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, swing

I am having a problem with the following Threaded Client Server program. All it should do is get values from text fields and on button press to save the data to the SQL db table. While I build everything it all builds successfully but the ClientGUI (swing) will not open. I believe my problem is in the the ConnectionCW class but cannot figure out what exactly I am supposed to do in the `void run`. Could you take a look and advice me on how to change the ConnectionCW to work fine? Thanks in advance! The code is down here:

**Servercode:**

```
package networkclientserver;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server 
 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    int connectionCount = 0;  // Count of clients connecting
    Thread connThread;
    System.out.println("Server starting");

    try
    {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(2000);
        while (true)
        {
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            // Network n;
            connectionCount++;
            System.out.println("Connection " + connectionCount + " made");

            //Create and start thread to process client requests
            connThread = new Thread(new ConnectionCW(s)
            {
            });
            connThread.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Trouble making a connection" + e);
    }
}

}
```

**ClientGUI:**

```
package networkclientserver;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; 
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;


public class ClientGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame 
  {

ObjectInputStream ios = null;
ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
Socket s;


public ClientGUI()
{

    initComponents();
    try
    {

        this.s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2000);
        this.ios = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        this.oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error connecting with the Server  " + e);
    }

       }

public static void main(String args[])
{


            ClientGUI gui = new ClientGUI();
            gui.setVisible(true);

}

  }
```

**ConnectionCW:**

```
 package networkclientserver;

 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.net.*;
 import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
 import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
 import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
 import java.util.logging.Level;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;

 class ConnectionCW implements Runnable
 {

private Socket s;

ConnectionCW(Socket s)
{
    this.s = s;

}

public void run()
{

    try
    {
        this.insertIntoTable();
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(ConnectionCW.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}  // end of method run*/

public void insertIntoTable() throws Exception
{

    ObjectInputStream oois = new ObjectInputStream(this.s.getInputStream());
    Network netW = (Network) oois.readObject();

    try
    {

        Connection conn = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement create = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO datatopology (numberNodes,numberHubs,numberSwitches,topologyStructure,country,status) VALUES ('" + netW.getNNodes() + "','" + netW.getNHubs() + "','" + netW.getNSwitches() + "','" + netW.getTopology() + "','" + netW.getCountry() + "','" + netW.getStatus() + "')");
        create.executeUpdate();
        oois.close();

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally
    {
        System.out.println("Function complete!");
    }

}

public Connection getConnection() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/networkstopology";
        String username = "user";
        String password = "pass";
        Class.forName(driver);

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        System.out.println("Connected to MySQL!");
        return conn;

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}

 }
```

Comment: with all respect, I guess you can not get good answer for questions like "please debug my code". Can you please rephrase your question, and post a simple self containing example? Also post what did you do, and how did you try to follow what is happening.

Comment: Start by having a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for reasons why you're having problems and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for some ideas about how to fix it